# Можно ли как то повлиять на лимиты функций json_decode и json_encode?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, outofmemoryerror, json-encode

Имею такую функцию, в которой считываю XML файл, достаю через XPath нужные данные и складываю в цикле в массив.

Есть функция `simple_xml_to_array` которая преобразует простой XML в массив.

При работе с файлами до 100мб, все нормально, свыше 100мб, нехватка памяти на строке преобразования `return json_decode(json_encode($element), true);`

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Не помогает.
Можно ли как то повлиять на лимиты функций `json_decode` и `json_encode` ?

```
protected function load_plg_param_ref_from_xml($file_values) {

    //  Считываем файл с харакстеристиками
    #-----------------------------
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("{$this->m_customs_path}$file_values");
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('tns', 'http://www.xxxx.ru/vietuemart/customs/export/param/ref');
    #-----------------------------

    //  Перебираем узлы [Ref]
    #-----------------------------
    $array_param_ref = $xml->xpath('/tns:VirtuemartCustoms/tns:Ref');

    foreach ($array_param_ref as $param_value) {
        $values[] = $this->simple_xml_to_array($param_value);
    }
    #-----------------------------

    unset($xml);

    return $values;

}


public function simple_xml_to_array(SimpleXMLElement $element) {

    return json_decode(json_encode($element), true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант написать свой обработчик с рекурсией вместо json_encode/decode

```
function SimpleXML2Array($xml) {   
    $array = (array)$xml;

    if (count($array) == 0) {
        $array = (string)$xml;  
    }

    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value){
            if (is_object($value)) {
                if(strpos(get_class($value),"SimpleXML")!==false){
                        $array[$key] = SimpleXML2Array($value);
                }
            } else {
                $array[$key] = SimpleXML2Array($value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```